# How to mix Mp3 files

Tags: delphi, mp3, delphi-2010, mixing

I would like to mix MP3 files with Delphi 2010.

Is this possible? Does anyone know of a `component`(set) I could use to get this done? Or maybe a runtime library? Any tips from someone with experience mixing MP3 files?

Comment: intersting would like to know this myself. @Kermia how would you want to mix the music? there is the FL Studio (fruity loops) way where you drag blocks into place, each block contains a wav or mp3 sample and are played seamlessly. The other way can be seen in a program such as Ejay (Virtual DJ) where you load a mp3 track on each deck. It might be useful if you provided additional information on how you would like to mix the track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use newAc:

http://symmetrica.net/newac/

it has a soundmixer component and supports mp3 inputs.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

FFmpeg has pascal headers, which apparently you can use from delphi: http://www.iversenit.dk/dev/ffmpeg-headers/

This should allow you to load mp3s or any other file type easily.

Answer (score 3):

Bass.dll, http://www.un4seen.com/

Comment: This answers your question.   You're asking for it to be done for you without you doing any work, Kermia? :-)

Comment: @Warren +1, I was thinking this too. Perhaps Kermia if you provided more information we may be able advise you better. There are several ways to mixing a mp3 file, you need to be a bit more specific. Do you want it to work like Audacity, Fruity Loops, Virtual DJ etc..?

Comment: Kermia, if you don't know how to use it, then how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: How guy with this questin and with these comments ( below ) can have silver ( !!! ) badge... I mean ..it is total nonsense ... SO badge system really needs remake as it clearly does not replicate anything ....

Answer (score 2):

If mixing two mp3 files means mixing the audio signal it is required to decode the mp3 first.

While mp3 contains a decomposed signal structure (fft of the audio signal) two independend mp3 files will probably differ too much in the encoding format to make any attempt of mixing undecoded audio.

For decoding and encoding you need an encoder like lame to convert mp3 to wav files. While streaming (DirectShow Filters) is nice to have a decode, mix, encode should be fairly easy to handle by calling the command line interface.

The lame encoder/decoder binarys are available for windows. Mixing wav is not very complicated as you basically overlay each channels by (a+b)/2.

Answer (score 2):

If your mixing/decoding/playing, I would use the libmad library as it is the fastest most accurate mp3 decoding library as it uses integer math to decode.

There is a delphi pas file for it here:

http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid7D732610F6E36ABA5CE09F5C6D3060FBB74B998E.aspx?s=mp3

Its pretty simple to use. Then you need to mix your two streams, which depends on the data format you choose to work in, I recommend float so you do not loose precision.

```
for i = 0 to samples do
  out[i] = (in1[i] + in2[i]) * 0.5;
```

The multiplication by 0.5 is the same as divide by 2, but much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using gstreamer

Answer (score 1):

There is few possible choices for MP3 file manipulations: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=3243

In my humble opinion, the Audio Tools Library looks most promising one as there are MPEG parsing included ... I have not used any of such tools jet, but it is in my schedule though ...

**ALSO**, as noted before, MP3 is ompressed format, which means you will need to decompress before actual activities with binary information inside file.

Hope it helps!

Cheers, HX.

Answer (score 1):

[Directshow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) could also be used for this task. There are Delphi header files for Directshow in a package called [DSPack](http://code.google.com/p/dspack/).

From the DSPack page:

> DSPack is a set of Components and
>   class to write Multimedia Applications
>   using MS Direct Show and DirectX
>   technologies.

For producing an mp3 file as result of overlapping the sound from the two input files, you will need to decompress the two audio files, do the mix and recompress them again. In both cases, you will need to go over the audio samples of both files, treating each channel independently, and averaging the values from input1 and input2 in your output file. It would be something like: `outsamples[i] := insamples1[i]/2 + insamples2[i]/2;`. For better peformance the expression `outsamples[i] := insamples1[i] shr 1 + insamples2[i] shr 1;` could be used instead.

For an approach maximizing both, performance and audio quality, I recommend this [post](http://www.vttoth.com/digimix.htm), it basically propose using the following expression (A and B are 0-1 normalized audio samples):

> ```
> Z = 2·A·B if both A<0.5 and B<0.5
> Z = 2(A+B) – 2·A·B – 1 otherwise
> ```

Other resources that could help:
[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)
[lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/)
[razorlame (lame interop for delphi)](http://www.dors.de/razorlame/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using bass ,Bassenc and lame encoder .

download lame encoder from http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php
and bass  from http://www.un4seen.com/
put bass.dll ,bass.pas,Bassenc.dll,bassenc.pas and lime.exe in same folder as your project exe file.
to use sample code put a listbox ,opendialog and two buttons on form

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, bass, bassenc,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    ListBox1.items.add(OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  decoder, encoder, newdecoder: dword;
  I, R: Integer;
  buf: array [1 .. 204800] of byte;


begin
  for I := 0 to ListBox1.items.count - 1 do
  begin
    if I = 0 then
    begin
      decoder := BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, PChar(ListBox1.items.strings[0]),
        0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE or BASS_UNICODE);
      encoder := BASS_Encode_Start(decoder,
        'lame.exe --alt-preset standard - fulltrack.mp3',
        BASS_ENCODE_AUTOFREE or BASS_UNICODE, nil, nil);

    end
    else
    begin
      newdecoder := BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, PChar(ListBox1.items.strings[I]
        ), 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE or BASS_UNICODE);



      if not BASS_Encode_SetChannel(encoder, newdecoder) then
      begin
        showmessage(inttostr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
        BASS_StreamFree(decoder);
        continue;
      end;
      BASS_StreamFree(decoder);

   // free the old decoder
      decoder := newdecoder;
    end;

    R := 1;
    while R > 0 do
    begin
      R := BASS_ChannelGetData(decoder, @buf, sizeof(buf));
    end;

  end;

  BASS_StreamFree(decoder); // free the decoder
  BASS_Encode_Stop(encoder); // stop the encoder
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, handle, nil) then
    showmessage('Error initializing audio!');
end;

end.
```